# How do I get "firebase login" to work from Google Cloud Shell

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-shell

I logged into Google Cloud Shell and found that that the Firebase CLI is already installed.

I then tried to run "firebase list" to see that it was working and was prompted to login.

"Visit this URL on any device to log in:"
`<very long URL>`

I copy/pasted the URL into a browser and got the standard "Firebase CLI would like to:" prompt from Google but when I approved it by clicking the "Allow" button, it failed.

This is the error page that showed.

This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 9005
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Run the following command in your terminal:

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

This will return a url that you can copy in the browser. After completing the steps, you'll receive back a code which you paste in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

run same command if logging in from within docker

Answer (score -1):

In cloudshell when following the above link, it gives: Authorization Error
Error 400: invalid_request
Required parameter is missing: response_type

But it does work from chromebook linux!